# Find location in radius

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation, coordinates, yahoo-api

I have a gps coordinate, I wish to get a list of adresses inside it's certain radius. From these adresses I wish to select the ones that are **companies** and contain specific **sector** name. (clothing, finance, metallurgy, etc..), I thought the returned api object may contain the necessary information to make the distinction. Is there a free api that has the necessary functions to bring me closer to my goal ? (like google maps, google places, yahoo placefinder, and similar applications.)

**Note:** I use the MVEL language, I guess it has access to some Java functions so you can consider me writing Java, but any information considering the MVEL language is also appreciated.

**Note2:** Radius is not an essential requisite, it would be enough if I found the adresses in a certain district. The classification however, is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take a look into :
[GoogleMapServicesJava](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)

Particulary into the Places API service :
[Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Where you can query a search sort by radius, place type, etc...

Hope that will help !

Comment: The answer was right in front of me, yet I accept this because it's correct.

Comment: Thanks, and you can get any place type for Places API here : [Places Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)